# How can I have only positive decimal numbers in Django using Python?

Tags: django, python-3.x

validators is  not working.NameError: name 'MinValueValidator' is not defined

Comment: Looks like you did not import the validator. Can you share relevants parts of the model?

Comment: from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    #id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

Answer (score 2):

You need to *import* the `MinValueValidator`, from the `django.core.validators` module:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Note that validations do *not* run on the database level, and are not performed on the model layer (unless you trigger these yourself, for example with `my_product.full_clean()`).

Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), Django has a framework to specify constraints for the database level. This however requires that the database supports checking constraints (some databases simply ignore `CHECK` clauses). You can specify this with:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models import constraints

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))]
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            constraints.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(price__gte=Decimal('0.01')),
                name='price_positive'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Not showing error but still not working in database.Can be selected negative value from drop down button in database

Comment: @mehedi1510: but validators do *not* run at the database level, in fact not on the models level either (unless you perform a `my_product.full_clean()` for example). The validators run when you enter data through a Django *form*.